# Replace regular expression with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Consider two regular expressions:

```
var regex_A = "Main\.(.+)\.Value";
var regex_B = "M_(.+)_Sp";
```

I want to be able to replace a string using regex_A as input, and regex_B as the replacement string. But also the other way around. And **without** supplying additional information like a format string per regex.

Specifically I want to create a replaced_B string from an input_A string. So:

```
var input_A = "Main.Rotating.Value";
var replaced_B = input_A.RegEx_Awesome_Replace(regex_A, regex_B);
Assert.AreEqual("M_Rotating_Sp", replaced_B);
```

And this should also work in reverse (thats the reason i can't use a simple string.format for regex_B). Because I don't want to supply a format string for every regular expression (i'm lazy).

```
var input_B = "M_Skew_Sp";
var replaced_A = input_B.RegEx_Awesome_Replace(regex_B, regex_A);
Assert.AreEqual("Main.Skew.Value", replaced_A);
```

I have no clue if this exists, or how to call it. Google search finds me all kinds of other regex replaces... not this one.

**Update:**

So basically I need a way to convert a regular expression to a format string.

```
var regex_A_format = Regex2Format(regex_A);
Assert.AreEqual("Main.$1.Value", regex_A_format);
```

and

```
var regex_B_format = Regex2Format(regex_B);
Assert.AreEqual("M_$1_Sp", regex_B_format);
```

So what should the RegEx_Awesome_Replace and/or Regex2Format function look like?

**Update 2:**

I guess the RegEx_Awesome_Replace should look something like (using some code from answers below):

```
public static class StringExtenstions
{
    public static string RegExAwesomeReplace(this string inputString,string searchPattern,string replacePattern)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(inputString, searchPattern, Regex2Format(replacePattern));
    }
}
```

Which would leave the Regex2Format as an open question.

Comment: Does Regex2Format(replacePattern) return string or another replace pattern? If it returns formatted string, how do you want the string to be formatted? and where is the information about the *formats*? If you want the format to be within `replacePattern`, how does it look like?

Comment: Have you narrowed down your requirement to a solvable problem?

Comment: No, I don't think the regular expressions really solve any real life problem. Makes more sense to define both expressions in a more simple manner.

Comment: Well, then this question should be closed, since there is no proper answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined way for one regex to refer to a match found in another regex. Regexes are not format strings.

What you can do is to use `Tuple`s of a format string together with its regex. e.g.

```
var a = new Tuple<Regex,string>(new Regex(@"(?<=Main\.).+(?=\.Value)"), @"Main.{0}.Value")
var b = new Tuple<Regex,string>(new Regex(@"(?<=M_).+(?=_Sp)"), @"M_{0}_Sp")`
```

Then you can pass these objects to a common replacement method in any order, like this:

```
private string RegEx_Awesome_Replace(string input, Tuple<Regex,string> toFind, Tuple<Regex,string> replaceWith)
{
    return string.Format(replaceWith.Item2, toFind.Item1.Match(input).Value);
}
```

You will notice that I have used [zero-width positive lookahead assertion and zero-width positive lookbehind assertions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) in my regexes, to ensure that `Value` contains exactly the text that I want to replace.

You may also want to add error handling, for cases where the match can not be found. Maybe read about [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I like this. But its not what I need. Now I still need to convert the regular expression to a format string (like string.format).

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify what you have as input. Are you writing the regexes yourself, or do they come from outside of your application e.g. as user input?

Comment: Outside from user input, from configuration files.  I added that I want the code for the functions. To make it extra clear that I don't want to add data. But ultimately its about more brevity from a configuration point.

Comment: Do they really need all the power of regular expressions? Or do you only need to capture some text between a prefix and a suffix?

Comment: Thats a good point. As a programmer I want the power of regular expressions, so you get a lot of extra flexibility. But that might not be needed in most cases indeed. I will sleep on that.

Comment: I think you need to refine what exactly constitutes valid expressions. All the grouping available for regex makes it very unclear what exactly you'd like to replace with.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already reduced your problem to where you need to change a `Regex` into a string format (implementing `Regex2Format`) I will focus my answer just on that part. Note that my answer is incomplete because it doesn't address the full breadth of parsing regex capturing groups, however it works for simple cases.

First thing needed is a Regex that will match Regex capture groups. There is a negative lookbehind to not match escaped bracket symbols. There are other cases that break this regex. E.g. a non-capturing group, wildcard symbols, things between square braces.

```
private static readonly Regex CaptureGroupMatcher = new Regex(@"(?<!\\)\([^\)]+\)");
```

The implementation of `Regex2Format` here basically writes everything outside of capture groups into the output string, and replaces the capture group value by `{x}`.

```
static string Regex2Format(string pattern)
{
    var targetBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int previousEndIndex = 0;
    int formatIndex = 0;
    foreach (Match match in CaptureGroupMatcher.Matches(pattern))
    {
        var group = match.Groups[0];
        int endIndex = group.Index;
        AppendPart(pattern, previousEndIndex, endIndex, targetBuilder);
        targetBuilder.Append('{');
        targetBuilder.Append(formatIndex++);
        targetBuilder.Append('}');
        previousEndIndex = group.Index + group.Length;
    }
    AppendPart(pattern, previousEndIndex, pattern.Length, targetBuilder);
    return targetBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This helper function writes pattern string values into the output, it currently writes everything except `\` characters used to escape something.

```
static void AppendPart(string pattern, int previousEndIndex, int endIndex, StringBuilder targetBuilder)
{
    for (int i = previousEndIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        char c = pattern[i];
        if (c == '\\' && i < pattern.Length - 1 && pattern[i + 1] != '\\')
        {
            //backslash not followed by another backslash - it's an escape char
        }
        else
        {
            targetBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

```
static void Test()
{
    var cases = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { @"Main\.(.+)\.Value", @"Main.{0}.Value" },
        { @"M_(.+)_Sp(.*)", "M_{0}_Sp{1}" },
        { @"M_\(.+)_Sp", @"M_(.+)_Sp" },
    };

    foreach (var kvp in cases)
    {
        if (PatternToStringFormat(kvp.Key) != kvp.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test failed for {0} - expected {1} but got {2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, PatternToStringFormat(kvp.Key));
        }
    }

}
```

To wrap up, here is the usage:

```
private static string AwesomeRegexReplace(string input, string sourcePattern, string targetPattern)
{
    var targetFormat = PatternToStringFormat(targetPattern);
    return Regex.Replace(input, sourcePattern, match =>
    {
        var args = match.Groups.OfType<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => g.Value).ToArray<object>();
        return string.Format(targetFormat, args);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
 var replaced_B = Regex.Replace(input_A, @"Main\.(.+)\.Value", @"M_$1_Sp");
```

Comment: Also cool/shorter way to do a parameterised regex replace. But not what I need. And i changed my question again to make it more clear that I don't want to supply/write a format string per regex.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public static class StringExtenstions
{
    public static string RegExAwesomeReplace(this string inputString,string searchPattern,string replacePattern)
    {
        Match searchMatch = Regex.Match(inputString,searchPattern);
        Match replaceMatch = Regex.Match(inputString, replacePattern);

        if (!searchMatch.Success || !replaceMatch.Success)
        {
            return inputString;
        }

        return inputString.Replace(searchMatch.Value, replaceMatch.Value);
    }
}
```

The string extension method returns the string with replaced value for search pattern and replace pattern.

This is how you call:

```
input_A.RegEx_Awesome_Replace(regex_A, regex_B);
```

Comment: The replace pattern isn't compatible with the input string, they are different formats. So that's not going to work.